# php array re populate keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Hi I have an array, I need to change the keys, in an orderly manner but don't change the order the values are. e.g.

```
$a = array (
 0=>'h',
 1=>'blabla',
 2=>'yes'
);
```

I used

```
unset($a[1]);
```

but i need the key to restart calculating the keys
0,1,2 ... etccc
so i don't end up with:

```
array(
 0 => 'h',
 2 => 'yes'
)
```

but it should come return:

```
array(
 0 => 'h',
 1 => 'yes'
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) on it:

```
$a = array (
 0=>'h',
 1=>'blabla',
 2=>'yes'
);

unset($a[1]);

$a = array_values($a);

var_dump($a); 
/*
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "h"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "yes"
}
*/
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to apply [array_values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) on your array to re-index.

```
$a = array_values($a);
```

Bonus: If you also need to order your values you can use [sort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) and it too will re-index your array.

*Note: By using any of array_values or sort you will loose any string keys you may have.*

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [array_splice()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) instead of unset(), which will automatically reindex the array elements:

```
$a = array (
 0=>'h',
 1=>'blabla',
 2=>'yes'
);

array_splice($a,1,1);

var_dump($a);
```

Comment: But that's a bit of an overkill. There are some other functions that will do that. array_merge for example (for his case).

Comment: Is it really overkill compared with executing an array_values() immediately after an unset()?

Comment: Assuming he wants to eliminate exactly one element I guess it may be a bit faster with array_splice, but I have no serious evidence. Also PHP is not exactly a language where speed should be the priority :). I'll give you a +1 for your combo solution to unset and re-index.

Comment: It might be interesting to see which was the faster method, but it would take a much larger array than the OP is using to see any difference in speed.