# How to displays keys of an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array looking so:

```
Array
(
 [0] => a
 [1] => b
 [3] => c
 [4] => d
 [15] => e
)
```

and i want to get something like that:

```
Array
(
 [0] => a
 [1] => b
 [2] => c
 [3] => d
 [4] => e
)
```

How do I get the intended effect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php array re populate keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123940/php-array-re-populate-keys) and [others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+array+reindex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$new_array = array_values($old_array); //this will return sorted  one
```

Answer (score 6):

```
array_values($array)
```

[Easy as pie :)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)