# PHP remove non-existing indexes from array and rearrange

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php array re populate keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123940/php-array-re-populate-keys)

is there a way to remove all the non-existing indexes from a php array and then rearrange it? For example

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [2] => b
    [3] => c
    [6] => d
)
```

**TO**

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
)
```

Big thanks!
Rik.

Answer (score 5):

Just use [this](http://php.net/array_values) built-in function

```
$array=array_values($array)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

```
$arr = array_values($arr);
```